# localhost 8080 not working even after installing all the features in karaf

Tags: localhost, apache-karaf, sdn, opendaylight

I started ./karaf process and installed all the necessary features like retsconf, netconf & dlux but still localhost 8080 or 8181 not opening. To avoid clash of ports i killed all the processes using this port. But still unable to get the UI. Can anyone help me in this case?

Comment: Is this a vanilla Apache Karaf, or some special custom distribution?

Comment: its 0.4.2-Beryllium-SR2.

Comment: ahh you're talking of opendaylight ... don't know how that handles it, a vanilla Karaf does have war and http features to install ...

Comment: change the port in jetty.xml to something other than 8181 and see if that is working fine or not. If it is not working then restart the apache